# '[object Object]' message in .reduce

Tags: javascript, object, reduce, arrow-functions

I am learning JS, and trying to figure out:
what is reason of appearing in console of [object Object]?

```
const arr = [true,1,'message1','message2']
const arr1 = arr.reduce(
    (acc, rec) => ({ ...acc, [`field${acc}${arr.indexOf(rec) + 1}`]: rec}),
{}
  )
```

console result:

```
[object Object] {
  field[object Object]1: true,
  field[object Object]2: 1,
  field[object Object]3: "message1",
  field[object Object]4: "message2"
}
```

Comment: where console.log() code btw?

Comment: Side note: You've said you're just learning JS, so some advice: Don't use `reduce` unless you're doing functional programming and the function you're passing to `reduce` is a utility function defined elsewhere and reused. If you aren't doing FP w/a predefined utility function, just use a loop. It's simpler to write, simpler to read. `reduce` is dramatically overused. Quoting [Brian Terlson](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544): *"I regret almost every time I've used Array#reduce. To current maintainers of my old code, yes that should have been a for loop, and I'm sorry."*

Comment: It's task from learning course, and the main rule is using only reduce.

Comment: @Nurbek - Then while the course may provide correct technical information, I wouldn't rely on it for best practices. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the right one:

```
const arr1 = arr.reduce(
    (acc, rec) => {return { ...acc, [`field${arr.indexOf(rec) + 1}`]: rec}},
{}
  )
```

also, you need to know that better way, will be add 3rd argument "index" to replace "arr.indexOf(rec)", so with it code will look:

```
const arr1 = arr.reduce(
    (acc, rec, index) => {return { ...acc, [`field${index + 1}`]: rec}},
{}
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

`${acc}` in an untagged template literal will convert `acc` to a string. Since it's an object and doesn't (apparently) have a custom `toString`, it will convert to `"[object Object]"`.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, but if you want to index into `acc` via the index you're getting in the next placeholder (`${arr.indexOf(rec) + 1}`), don't separate them, put them in the *same* placeholder.